# knitr: precede positive numbers with plus sign

Tags: r, knitr

I use knitr to have LaTeX pull numbers directly from R output, e.g., using `\Sexpr{res$a[1]}` to `\Sexpr{res$a[5]}`. Is there a way to automatically precede positive numbers with a plus sign? Sure, I could add plus signs to relevant numbers manually, but this seems to defeat the purpose of knitr.

Comment: Define a function `with_plus <- function (x) if (x>0) sprintf ("+ %s", x) else x` then use `\Sexpr {with_plus (res $a [1])}`

Comment: Sure, this would work but it yields a string that renders all knitr options regulating rounding etc. useless. I was hoping there would be a way of solving this issue within knitr.

Comment: Oh. I see. When I'm at a computer I might be able to dream up a solution. My approach would be to access the knitr rounding options within your function.

Comment: Great, thanks. I just noted that for my particular task, your suggestion worked just fine. Feel free to make it an answer but also feel free to find a more general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry it took me a while to get back to this.  And it turned out to be easier than I thought.  `knitr` doesn't appear to have its own options for controlling printing options.  Instead, it relies on the options from your R session.

Now consider the following:

```
x <- 5.1234567899876543

x
[1] 5.123457

options()$digits
[1] 7
```

So the way the number is printed to the console is (partially) determined by `options("digits")`.  Now, watch what happens when we apply the `format` function to `x` with all of the default arguments:

```
format(x)
[1] "5.123457"
```

We get back a character string that matches the representation when we simply printed `x`.  Let's leverage this to our benefit:

```
with_plus <- function(x, ...)
{
  if (x > 0)
  {
    sprintf(
      fmt = "+ %s", 
      format(x, ...)
    )
  }
  else
  {
    x
  }
}

with_plus(x)
[1] "+ 5.123457"
```

Now you have a function that, under the default settings, will print numbers the same way they appear in the console but with a "+" prepended to positive numbers.  Using `format`, you also get the flexibility to adjust individual values as needed.

Comment: excellent. You mean x > 0, though. Can you edit this? It won't let me unless I change six characters.

Comment: `x < 0` ... `x > 0` ... now you're just being picky. :)